# Add a range of numbers to the select > option tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I am making a date selector an I would was wondering if there is a way to set a range of numbers to accomplish this. Take the months field for example, I would like to set a range from 01-12. is this possible in just plain HTML.

What I really want to know is what is the accepted practice for doing this.

Comment: I didn't try anything in HTML alone. I used Javascript but then I thought using JavaScript for this might not be a common practice.

Comment: Well The truth is I want to know what is the accepted practice

Comment: What type of fields are you using? Are you going to have separate fields for Month, day, date, year? Or are you going to the more used input box with a calendar? I don't really see what your problem is as defined. Best practices is whatever works for you. Don't bother with what others accept as there will always be a dissenter. Javascript is really the only way you will enforce ranges (unless you have some flash component you want to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think [here](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/html5-date-picker.html) you can find the answer :)

Accepted practice is to use some script language like PHP, JavaScript or other....

Comment: not really what Im going for, but I edited the question to make my intentions more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This For Range value

```js
function show_value(x)
            {
             document.getElementById("slider_value").innerHTML='$'+x;
            }
```

```html
<span id="slider_value" style="color:red;font-size: 19px; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 45%;">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10000" name="sld3" value="100" onchange="show_value(this.value);">
```